# Does anyone know if this is notated properly, or how to properly notate this rhythm?

Tags: rhythm, jazz, time-signatures, ukulele

I wrote this little melody/riff here:

[image]

And while it sounds correct, I'm not sure if it's notated properly, with the correct time signatures and all. Could both the first 3/4 bars and the 2/4 bar be condensed into a 4/4 somehow, or how does all that work?

Answer (score 6):

It looks fine to me. It would also fit into 4/4 but the main difference is where the accents fall. Usually, you want the downbeat to be the strongest beat in the measure. Combining the first line into two 4/4 bars would mean that the second beat of your current 2/4 bar would become a downbeat. If that doesn't seem right to you, I would keep it the way you have it. It's hard to say for sure without hearing it in the context of a piece of music, but I think it is fine the way it is.

Also, I'm not familiar with ukulele so I might be mistaken, but it looks like you have a notation error on the last chord. Outside of a few wacky 20th century composers, sharps and flats carry through the measure -- you have a C# repeated in the score while it looks like the tab says to play a C natural. Sorry if I'm off-base here.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Not sure if you're still there but wrote some drums that i think fit with it and slowed it down since it feels more cloudy that way. 

[Here](https://gyazo.com/147f89ec1e5c02603103877b5af07570)

Now, are those drums in a specific time signature or i can just roll with that? (I mean i know i can just roll with that, but idk who knows i want it to be properly notated). Also dw about the actual key and all that since i wrote it on the tab first, but you are most likely correct since it switches key at the end.

[Here's](https://clyp.it/widoylvj) how it sounds

Comment: Your audio gave me a not found error (maybe I got to it too late), but those drums don't look like they're particularly strongly 4/4 to me, and if anything, I'm even more convinced that it's fine how you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Bar 7 is an F minor seventh triad, and should be written with flats (F-A♭-C-E♭). Most of the time, that A♯ note in bar 8 should be a B♭. Bar 8's G♯ should be an A♭, in my opinion. Same in Bar 9 to make the D diminished triad. Bar 10 has that weird chord. What is that? It's fine, but generally that would use D♭ as the root (D♭ diminished?)?. Rhythmwise, it looks good to me!

You said it switches key at the end. In the sheet music, this should probably be notated in the key signature. Sounds good!